# How to make Blender 2.8 remember collections Outliner state when i save and reopen the file?

Tags: groups, collections, outliner

If you create bunch of collections and arrange them in outliner, you "close" some of them and "open" others (with little arrow left to the collection name in Outliner), save the file, exit and open file again - Blender 2.8 won't respect the state you left your collection in when you saved the file, all of them will be "opened" creating a mess, every time i open the file i have to go through and close all collections again. This is one of the small things that really ruin user expirience for me when working in production in new Blender 2.8.

Not sure if i should ask separate question: Blender 2.8 also don't respect what filters i have active in Outliner (things like "Diable in Render" "Selectable") when saving and opening the file, how to fix that?

How to fix that behavior?

Comment: Hello :). Weird. That doesn't seem like a correct behavior, it's supposed to remember all of that. It works just fine on my end.

Comment: Although the Thread is old but the problem is still present. (2.92) The Closed/Open state of a collection is still not preserved. Quite annoying if you have a lot of Collections...